# Search for Multiple Elements in Column of a Dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, and I have a list of ID's I want to search through to check if they're in that dataframe. This dataframe looks as such:

```
dput(bed,"mybed.bed")
sample <- c("13874.p1", "13609.p1","12736.p1", "11970.p1","12025.p1","12189.p1","12529.p1","11522.p1","11716.p1","13684.p1")
```

I would like to return the rows of the dataframe containing any one of the values shared by the `sample` vector and `df$sample_ID`.

I tried using `sapply(samples, grepl, df$sample_ID)`, but it only if checks the first element of sample is present. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: sry misread the question. Could you provide the sample data.

Comment: Its in the question.

Comment: Difficult to get that into R, you can provide it with `dput()`

Comment: Ok, I did dput(bed,"mybed.bed"). I assume this is what you mean?

Comment: I cant see it in the post?

Comment: @Workhorse I posted an answer considering the general idea. Please provide a runnable example so we can help you with your concrete problem. We know the value of `sample`, but we don't know the values of `df$sample_ID`

Answer (score 1):

Calling :

```
unique(do.call(c, sapply(X = sample, FUN = function(x){return(grep(pattern = x,x = df$sample_id) )})))
```

should work :

```
> df = data.frame(chrom = c(1,2,1,1), 
+                 sample_id = c("12613.p1", "12613.p1","11118.p1,11120.p1,11199.p1,11226.p1,11285.p1,11296.p1,11333.p1,11374.p1,11388.p1,11395.p1,11420.p1", "11401.p1,13863.p1"), 
+                 stringsAsFactors = F)
> 
> 
> 
> sample <- c("13874.p1", "13609.p1","12736.p1", "11970.p1","12025.p1",
+             "12189.p1","12529.p1","11522.p1","11716.p1","13684.p1")
> 
> 
> unique(do.call(c, sapply(X = sample, FUN = function(x)   {return(grep(pattern = x,x = df$sample_id) )})))
integer(0)
```

no solution

But if I add a last string to sample :

```
> sample <- c("13874.p1", "13609.p1","12736.p1", "11970.p1","12025.p1",
+             "12189.p1","12529.p1","11522.p1","11716.p1","13684.p1",
+             "11199.p1")
> 
> 
> unique(do.call(c, sapply(X = sample, FUN = function(x){return(grep(pattern = x,x = df$sample_id) )})))
[1] 3
```

It works !!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got a solution for this, using: `str_locate_all` from `stringr` package. For example:

```
v <- c("abc11", "abc11abc11", "abc11abc11abc11abc")
library(stringr)
result1 <- str_locate_all(v[1], "11")
result2 <- str_locate_all(v[2], "11")
result3 <- str_locate_all(v[3], "11")
```

The output will show a row per match with a pair of values start-end (of the match):

```
> result1
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     4   5

> result2
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     4   5
[2,]     9  10

> result3
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     4   5
[2,]     9  10
[3,]    14  15
>
```

The result is stored in a little uncomfortable structure:

```
> class(result3)
[1] "list"
> length(result3)
[1] 1
>
```

And this unique element is an integer matrix:

```
> class(result3[[1]])
[1] "matrix"
> dim(result3[[1]])
[1] 3 2
>
```

The function `str_locate` provides a simpler output, but it will find only the first match.

**My recommendation** would be to extract this first element of the list and then operate with it, for example:

`m <- result3[[1]]`

Not it would be easier to get access to the information stored as a matrix 3x2 for `result3`:

```
> m
     start end
[1,]     4   5
[2,]     9  10
[3,]    14  15
```

Now, to know the number of matches:

```
> nrow(m)
[1] 3
```

or `dim(m)[1]`.

So with the result stored in a matrix form is it easier to extract the information. To get all the matched positions on the input argument just extract the first column:

```
> m[,1]
[1]  4  9 14
```

`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

**EDIT**

Apply the previous concepts to the original problem, i.e. find the matches for an array of m-patterns within an array of n-values.

`--------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

Back to what I understand is your problem, let's say we have the following data frame:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4), 
sample_ID = c(
    "12613.p1", 
    "12613.p1",
    "11401.p1,11120.p1,11199.p1,11226.p1,11395.p1,11296.p1,11333.p1,11374.p1,11388.p1,11395.p1,11420.p1", 
   "11401.p1,13863.p1"), 
 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Now we have the following sample vector:

```
sample <- c("11120.p1", "11395.p1", "12613.p1", "13863.p1", "11401.p1")
```

The `df`has 4-rows and the `sample` array has 5-rows. Now based on the previous explanation, lets to search where in `df$sample_ID` we can find the elements of `sample` using `lapply`function:

```
library(stringr)
all <- sapply(df$sample_ID, FUN = function(x) {return(str_locate_all(x, sample))})
```

Now output will be:

```
> class(all)
[1] "matrix"
```

where

```
> dim(all)
[1] 5 4
```

Therefore for each element of `sample`we have 5-columns with the result for a given row from the `df$sample_ID` (four columns).

We expect for each element of `sample` the following match:

```
Sample   | df$sample_ID[1]  | df$sample_ID[2]  | df$sample_ID[3] | df$sample_ID[4]
-------  | -----------------|------------------|-----------------|---------------
11120.p1 |      0           |        0         |       1         |       0       
11395.p1 |      0           |        0         |       2         |       0       
12613.p1 |      1           |        1         |       0         |       0       
13863.p1 |      0           |        0         |       0         |       1       
11401.p1 |      1           |        0         |       1         |       0
```

This is the result obtained:

```
> all
     12613.p1  12613.p1 
[1,] Integer,0 Integer,0
[2,] Integer,0 Integer,0
[3,] Integer,2 Integer,2
[4,] Integer,0 Integer,0
[5,] Integer,0 Integer,0
     11401.p1,11120.p1,11199.p1,11226.p1,11395.p1,11296.p1,11333.p1,11374.p1,11388.p1,11395.p1,11420.p1
[1,] Integer,2                                                                                         
[2,] Integer,4                                                                                         
[3,] Integer,0                                                                                         
[4,] Integer,0                                                                                         
[5,] Integer,2                                                                                         
     11401.p1,13863.p1
[1,] Integer,0        
[2,] Integer,0        
[3,] Integer,0        
[4,] Integer,2        
[5,] Integer,2        
>
```

Each element of matrix is a `list`. Here is how to understand the result, for each `[row, col]` it provides a summarized information about the `list` elements: `Integer,n` will indicate the number of elements of the given cell. For each match we have two values: [`start`,`end`], Therefore for m-matches we are going to have `m x 2`. That is why for `[row, col] = [2,3]` it has the value `4`.

To extract the information, lets say for the match at value: `sample[2]=11395.p1` for the third row (`df$sample_ID[3]`) we have:

```
> all[2,3]
$`11401.p1,11120.p1,11199.p1,11226.p1,11395.p1,11296.p1,11333.p1,11374.p1,11388.p1,11395.p1,11420.p1`
     start end
[1,]    37  44
[2,]    82  89
```

To extract all matches positions:

```
> all[2,3][[1]][,1]
[1] 37 82
```

For example: `m <- all[2,3][[1]]` then:

```
> m[,1]
[1] 37 82
```

*How to identify a non-match condition?*

Let's pick the element `[1,1]` of the original matrix, where there is no match, then:

```
> m <- all[1,1][[1]]
> dim(m)
[1] 0 2
> dim(m)[1]
[1] 0
>
```

I hope this solve your specific problem now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a simple solution to this problem (apologies for not posting more realistic data, my dataset is enormous).

So I have a character vector of IDs, `sample`. I then have a table, in which one column contains a list of ID's per row.

```
hits <- c()
for(i in sample){
       hits <- append(hits, which(grepl(i, df$sample_ID, fixed = TRUE)))
}

hits2 <- unique(hits)
```

I just go through the `sample` vector, and each time I check to see if it exists in each df$sample_ID list. It returns the row number (from the dataframe) of each positive hit. Since some rows might have 2 matches, I delete duplicates.

I can then subset based on these rows.

```
df2 <- df[hits2,]
```